# Recursive Reassignment of Variables in Clojure

Tags: recursion, clojure, immutability, let

I'm trying to get more acquainted with Clojre so I decided to do my Runge Kutta integrator project in it. However I'm having problems working with the immutable nature of the *let* statement. I want to evaluate 8 variables in each iteration of the loop and use them to recurse through it until my loop is finished.

The way I understand it, since my *recur* is inside the *let*'s scope, my k's and l's won't be overwritten with each recursion. I'm looking for a more idiomatic way to recurse through my integrator.

```
(loop [psin 0  Xin 1 xn dx] ;initial values
  (if (> xn 1)
    psin
    (let [k1 (evalg  xn psin) ;define 4 variables to calculate next step of Xi, psi
          l1 (evalf  xn Xin)  ;evalf and evalg evaluate the functions as per Runge Kutta
          k2 (evalg (+ (* 0.5 dx) xn) (+ (* 0.5 l1) psin))
          l2 (evalf (+ (* 0.5 dx) xn) (+ (* 0.5 k1) Xin))
          k3 (evalg (+ (* 0.5 dx) xn) (+ (* 0.5 l2) psin))
          l3 (evalf (+ (* 0.5 dx) xn) (+ (* 0.5 k2) Xin))
          k4 (evalg (+ dx xn) (+ l3 psin))
          l4 (evalf (+ dx xn) (+ k3 Xin))]
      (do
        (let [Xinew (+ Xin (* (/ dx 6) (+ k1 k4 (* 2 k3) (* 2 k2))) )
              psinew (+ psin (* (/ dx 6) (+ l1 l4 (* 2 l2) (* 2 l3) )))]
          (println k1)
          (recur psinew Xinew (+ dx xn)))))))
```

Many thanks! Looking forward to getting more acquainted with clojure:)

Comment: I don't think your understanding is correct - the `let` bindings will be re-evaluated on each loop iteration. Did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

First, as @Alex has commented, the `recur` does evaluate your `k`s and `l`s afresh on every iteration of the `loop`. A `recur` refers to its immediately enclosing function or loop form, in this case the latter.

---

The `(println k1)` suggests that what you are looking for is a sequence of `k1`s as you iterate round the `loop`.

Clojure has the concept of a *lazy [sequence](http://clojure.org/sequences)*: a potentially endless sequence of values that are

- calculated when called for
- forgotten if/when no longer accessible (garbage collected).

You should

- frame the solution as a lazy-sequence of `k1`s and - while we're at
  it -
- make your `evalg` and `evalf` functions arguments to your `runge-kutta`
  function.

We could build our lazy sequence from scratch, using explicit recursion wrapped in the [`lazy-seq` macro](http://grimoire.arrdem.com/1.6.0/clojure.core/lazy-seq/), but there is a whole library of sequence functions to hand, one of which will usually express your intent. These can be faster than what you or I would write, but will still be much slower than your `loop`.

A handy function here is [`iterate`](http://grimoire.arrdem.com/1.6.0/clojure.core/iterate/). We can systematically convert your `loop` to use it as follows:

- Convert the several `loop` arguments into a single [destructured](http://clojure.org/special_forms#binding-forms)
  vector argument to a local function (which I've called `step`).
- Include any result you want, in this case `k1` in the argument list.
- Rewrite the iteration to return what were the next set of arguments
  to the loop as a vector.
- Call `map` on the resulting sequence to get the data you want.

My best guess is the following:

```
(defn runge-kutta [evalg evalf dx]
  (letfn [(step [[k1 psin  Xin xn]]
                (let [k1 (evalg  xn psin)
                      l1 (evalf  xn Xin)
                      k2 (evalg (+ (* 0.5 dx) xn) (+ (* 0.5 l1) psin))
                      l2 (evalf (+ (* 0.5 dx) xn) (+ (* 0.5 k1) Xin))
                      k3 (evalg (+ (* 0.5 dx) xn) (+ (* 0.5 l2) psin))
                      l3 (evalf (+ (* 0.5 dx) xn) (+ (* 0.5 k2) Xin))
                      k4 (evalg (+ dx xn) (+ l3 psin))
                      l4 (evalf (+ dx xn) (+ k3 Xin))
                      Xinew (+ Xin (* (/ dx 6) (+ k1 k4 (* 2 k3) (* 2 k2))) )
                      psinew (+ psin (* (/ dx 6) (+ l1 l4 (* 2 l2) (* 2 l3) )))]
                  [k1 psinew Xinew (+ dx xn)]))]
    (map first (iterate step [nil 0 1 dx]))))
```

There may well be errors in this, as I'm groping in the dark.

The sequence is endless. You can stop it

- by returning the `xn`s too, and wrapping the result in a `take-while`
  or
- working out how may iterations you want - it looks like `(long (/ dx))`, 
  though there may be a one-off error there. Then just use `nth`
  or `take` to get what you want.

Let us know how you get on.